# How to fetch data from pagination URL with Feed Me plugin

Tags: plugin-feedme, querystring, api

I have a pagination URL http://example.com/v3/?limit=12&page=1

I try this code:

```
{% set page = craft.app.request.getParam('p') %}
{% set params = {
    url: 'http://example.com/v3/?limit=12&page=' ~ page,
    type: 'json',
    element: 'data',
    cache: 60,
} %}

{% set feed = craft.feedme.feed(params) %}
```

When accessing the URL `http://mysite.com/?p=1` I got the error 'Page not found'. Please share your idea and thanks for your answer!

Comment: My first guess: This sounds more like a routing issue than a Feed Me problem. Are you sure you are not getting the error when you remove the Feed Me code?

Comment: That seems `craft.app.request.getParam('p')` doesn't work, so is there any GET request? Sometimes, I need a GET request to show/hide elements.